# Python slice/index evaluation order (before list definition)

Tags: python, syntax

I was wondering if there is a reason why python evaluates the slicing/indexing after the definition of a list/tuple ?

(This question concerns Python [Code Golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) so I know it's not readable or "good practice", it's just about the accepted syntax and the fundamental behavior of the language.)

We can use index to mimic the ternary operator's behavior:

```py
a if x > 9 else b
(b,a)[x>9]  # way shorter
```

But this has an issue: the content of the tuple is evaluated before the condition in the index.

I created an example to illustrate the point: a function `f` that reduces the size of a string by one recursively till the string is empty, then returns 0

```py
f = lambda s: f(s) if len(s:=s[:-1]) else 0
print(f("abc"))  # works fine

f = lambda s: (0, f(s))[len(s:=s[:-1])==0]
print(f("abc"))  # max recursion depth error
```

The recursion depth error occurs because the tuple definition is evaluated before the index. It means that what is in the slice/index doesn't matter, the function will be called again and again.

I don't really understand why python doesn't evaluate the slice/index before because even an obvious case like the following fails:

```py
f = lambda: (0, f())[0]
f()  # max recursion depth error
```

On top of that, it could benefit in terms of memory usage and runtime if we just evaluate the single element (or the slice) we want from the array and not every single element:

```py
x = 2
print([long_computation(), other_long_computation(), 0][x])
```

Is there any reason not to evaluate the slice/index before the tuple definition ?

Comment: You can't slice something that doesn't exist yet. (Also, that's indexing, not slicing.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes it's more about indexing :) The tuple could exist but without evaluating its elements, kinda like that `f = lambda s: (lambda: 0, lambda: f(s))[len(s:=s[:-1])==0]()` which works

Comment: So you really want a tuple with lazy evaluation of its members?  There may be a way to do that in Python, but I don't know how and it certainly wouldn't be worth the trouble.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes I would like lazy tuple evaluation when `[...]` index/slice directly follows as I don't see why the rest should be evaluated because it will be left over by the slicing, the evaluation would happen for kept elements directly after slicing

Comment: But that would *only* be useful for code golf, a use case that the Python dev team has no desire to encourage. For anyone not doing code golf, it just adds complexity and weird edge cases to the language.

Comment: Plus, changing the language to work like that now would silently break backward compatibility, changing the behavior of existing code. If someone was using `(do_thing(), compute_value())[1]` as a hacky workaround to get something like the behavior of C's comma operator, now `do_thing()` doesn't happen.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I disagree, it could benefit in terms of memory usage and runtime because it won't evaluate the things it does not need to. About the backward compatibility, yeah that's a big issue sadly... For me, it would feel natural to have lazy evaluation to be the default way.

Comment: It would only have those benefits in a single, very specific code pattern that basically only shows up in code golf. For anyone else, there's `x if y else z`.

Comment: If you want lazy evaluation to be default, use Haskell or something. Python is far too imperative a language to default to lazy evaluation. Side effects need to occur at predictable times, not unexpectedly because some code finally happened to force a value 5 hours later.

Answer (score -2):

Humans read left-to-right, the parser reads left-to-right, the compiler just converts whatever is parsed into bytecode. It would make sense- and it's easier- to just parse it left-to-right rather than adding special cases for stuff that can be already done properly in the left-to-right fashion. Why do you need to do this anyways? You don't *need* to do it. You can already do it properly in the current parser and compiler. The complexity of this special case and how rare it's ever used, both factors are enough as reasons to not evaluate the slice before the tuple definition.

Comment: The ternary operator is a counter example, not evaluated from left to right. And I don't need to specify why I want something, I just want answers...

Comment: @Gruvw I gave you another answer: how rare it is ever used is a reason not to evaluate the slice before the tuple definition. You can also suggest this in the python ideas mailing list, but the reason I mentioned in this comment may likely be given to you.

Comment: @Gruvw also, it would break some code that relies on evaluating the tuple first.

Comment: I disagree with you about how "rare" it would occur as I often use tuples and indexing like that (not often using recursion, but I also gave a simple example with `long_computation()`). However, backward compatibility is the biggest issue to this idea. That being said, my question was more about why python do it that way than about we need to change this.

Comment: You have already got your answer in the comments anyway, so I won't argue anymore.